# When a merge-conflict happens and two options are shown, what is the magit command that allows the user to easily pick one of them?

Tags: magit, git, commands

Suppose a merge conflict happens. There are two options shown the upper (in red) and the lower (in green):

[image]

I would like to avoid complex `ediff-mode` stuff to pick one. I have seen some tutorial where the user would easily pick one of the them with a command. I believe it is a magit command.

What is the magit command to easily pick one of them?

Comment: There's `smerge-keep-current`, bound to `C-c ^ RET` that chooses the option under the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `smerge-keep-lower` to pick the lower (green) or `smerge-keep-upper` to get the upper (red) version. These are the commands.

Note: they are **not** magit commands! See documentation:

```
smerge-keep-lower is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘smerge-mode.el’.

(smerge-keep-lower)

Keep the "lower" version of a merge conflict.
In a conflict that looks like:
  <<<<<<<
  UUU
  =======
  LLL
  >>>>>>>
this keeps "LLL".
```